# How can I use multiprocessing to migrate database in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlite, python-multiprocessing

I have a script used to migrate data from SQLite to Postgres in Python. I'm using it with `multiprocessing` module to speed up program but I got some errors. Can someone help me edit it? Thanks.

Here my script :

```
import time
import multiprocessing

sqdb="C://Users//duongnb//Desktop//Python//SqliteToPostgreFull//testmydb6.db" #folder contain sqlite db
sqlike="table"
pgdb="testmydb11" #postgres db
pguser="postgres"
pgpswd="1234"
pghost="127.0.0.1"
pgport="5432"


consq=sqlite3.connect(sqdb)
cursq=consq.cursor()

tabnames=[]
print() 
cursq.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" AND name LIKE "%table%";')
tabgrab = cursq.fetchall()
for item in tabgrab:
    tabnames.append(item[0])
print(tabgrab)

def copyTable(table):
        cursq.execute("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = ?;", (table,))
        create = cursq.fetchone()[0]
        cursq.execute("SELECT * FROM %s;" %table)
        rows=cursq.fetchall()
        colcount=len(rows[0])
        pholder='%s,'*colcount
        newholder=pholder[:-1]

        try:

            conpg = psycopg2.connect(database=pgdb, user=pguser, password=pgpswd,
                                host=pghost, port=pgport)
            curpg = conpg.cursor()
            curpg.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s;" %table)
            create = create.replace("AUTOINCREMENT", "")
            curpg.execute(create)
            curpg.executemany("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s);" % (table, newholder),rows)
            conpg.commit()

            if conpg:
                conpg.close()

        except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
            print ('Error %s' % e) 
            sys.exit(1)

        finally:
            print("Complete")    

consq.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    for table in tabnames:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target = copyTable, args = (table))
        p.start()
    for table in tabnames:
        p.join()
    print("All processes finished.")      

    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Duration {duration} seconds")
```

My error :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.535]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

(base) C:\Users\duongnb\Desktop\Python>python -u "c:\Users\duongnb\Desktop\Python\SqliteToPostgreFull\sqq.py"

[('table1',), ('table2',), ('table3',), ('table4',), ('table5',), ('table6',), ('table7',), ('table8',), ('table9',), ('table10',)]

[('table1',), ('table2',), ('table3',), ('table4',), ('table5',), ('table6',), ('table7',), ('table8',), ('table9',), ('table10',)]
Process Process-2:

Traceback (most recent call last):

[('table1',), ('table2',), ('table3',), ('table4',), ('table5',), ('table6',), ('table7',), ('table8',), ('table9',), ('table10',)]
Process Process-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: copyTable() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given

[('table1',), ('table2',), ('table3',), ('table4',), ('table5',), ('table6',), ('table7',), ('table8',), ('table9',), ('table10',)]
Process Process-6:
[('table1',), ('table2',), ('table3',), ('table4',), ('table5',), ('table6',), ('table7',), ('table8',), ('table9',), ('table10',)]

  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()

Traceback (most recent call last):

Process Process-5:
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
[('table1',), ('table2',), ('table3',), ('table4',), ('table5',), ('table6',), ('table7',), ('table8',), ('table9',), ('table10',)]
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: copyTable() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
[('table1',), ('table2',), ('table3',), ('table4',), ('table5',), ('table6',), ('table7',), ('table8',), ('table9',), ('table10',)]
TypeError: copyTable() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given
Process Process-3:
Process Process-7:
TypeError: copyTable() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given

[('table1',), ('table2',), ('table3',), ('table4',), ('table5',), ('table6',), ('table7',), ('table8',), ('table9',), ('table10',)]
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
[('table1',), ('table2',), ('table3',), ('table4',), ('table5',), ('table6',), ('table7',), ('table8',), ('table9',), ('table10',)]
Traceback (most recent call last):

Process Process-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: copyTable() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given
[('table1',), ('table2',), ('table3',), ('table4',), ('table5',), ('table6',), ('table7',), ('table8',), ('table9',), ('table10',)]
Process Process-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: copyTable() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: copyTable() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given
TypeError: copyTable() takes 1 positional argument but 7 were given
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: copyTable() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given
[('table1',), ('table2',), ('table3',), ('table4',), ('table5',), ('table6',), ('table7',), ('table8',), ('table9',), ('table10',)]
All processes finished.
Duration 0.22240376472473145 seconds
Process Process-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: copyTable() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given

(base) C:\Users\duongnb\Desktop\Python>C:/Users/duongnb/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Scripts/activate

(base) C:\Users\duongnb\Desktop\Python>conda activate base

(base) C:\Users\duongnb\Desktop\Python>
```

Comment: Try `args = (table,)`?

Comment: @Shawn It works, thanks for your help. But what is the difference here?

Comment: `multiprocessing.Process()` has a parameter `args=()` which requires a tuple. `(table)` is not a tuple, it is a variable containing a string value between parentheses. `tuple(table)` or `(table,)` is a tuple with 1 item, `(table, table)` is a tuple with 2 items, ...